# Как сделать календарь из определенного диапазона дат?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, хотелось бы узнать как можно сделать календарь их определенного диапазона дат? Допустим с 2021.07.28 по 2022.05.28. Или есть какая-то библиотека со схожим функционалом? Желательно на js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я приведу пример с минимальной стилизацией, который демонстрирует как работать с датами. В JavaScript есть достаточно гибкий объект `Date`, поддерживающий "автоисправление". Это позволяет совершать легкие прогулки по времени, не заботясь о структуре календаря. Код небольшой и в подробных комментариях не нуждается, изучайте и развивайте в соответствии со своими потребностями.

```js
const cal = document.getElementById('calendar');
const hdr = '<div>пн</div><div>вт</div><div>ср</div><div>чт</div><div>пт</div><div>сб</div><div>вс</div>';
const getTitle = (d, y) => `<div class="title">${d+1 + '.' + y}</div>`;

let dStart = new Date('2021-07-28');
let dEnd = new Date('2022-05-28');

let ds = new Date(dStart);
let de = new Date(dEnd);

ds.setDate(1);
de.setMonth(dEnd.getMonth() + 1, 1);
de.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

let eMonth = null;

while (ds < de)
{
  let day = ds.getDate();
  let dayOfWeek = ds.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : ds.getDay();
  let dayDiv = document.createElement('div');

  if (day == 1)
  {
    cal.appendChild(eMonth = document.createElement('div'));
    eMonth.innerHTML = getTitle(ds.getMonth(), ds.getFullYear()) + hdr;
    dayDiv.style.gridColumn = dayOfWeek;
  }

  dayDiv.innerText = day;

  if (ds < dStart || ds > dEnd) dayDiv.className = 'not-in-range';
  else if (dayOfWeek > 5) dayDiv.className = 'holiday';

  eMonth.appendChild(dayDiv);

  ds.setDate(ds.getDate() + 1);
}
```

```css
#calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#calendar>div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 30px);
  grid-template-rows: 30px;
  column-gap: 2px;
  row-gap: 2px;
  margin: 12px 7px;
}

#calendar>div>div { text-align: center; }

.title { grid-column: span 7; }
.holiday { color: red; }
.not-in-range { color: lightgray; }
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```